# Is there any way to make a script to get corners of rasterized shapes in Photoshop?

Tags: javascript, opencv, photoshop, photoshop-script

I want to make a code giving me the corners of a rasterized layer/shape in Photoshop (uploaded an image for sample).
My code is working but only for boxes/rectangles. But when an image/shape is slanted, my code gives me the wrong coordinates. I think because when an image is slanted, it detects a lot of corners in Photoshop.

I already tried this code:

```
var doc = app.activeDocument;

var selectedLayer = doc.activeLayer;

if (selectedLayer.kind == LayerKind.NORMAL) {
    var bounds = selectedLayer.bounds;

    var topLeft = [bounds[0].value, bounds[1].value];
    var topRight = [bounds[2].value, bounds[1].value];
    var bottomLeft = [bounds[0].value, bounds[3].value];
    var bottomRight = [bounds[2].value, bounds[3].value];

    alert("Top Left: " + topLeft + "\n" +
          "Top Right: " + topRight + "\n" +
          "Bottom Left: " + bottomLeft + "\n" +
          "Bottom Right: " + bottomRight);
} else {
    alert("Please select a rasterized image.");
}
```

What did I do wrong or what's lacking in my code to detect just the corners of the raster image?

Comment: Perhaps this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59334122/how-can-i-get-coordinates-of-points-of-contour-corners-in-opencv-js

Comment: The layerbounds finds the smallest rectangle that a layer can contain - it doesn't take into account shape. So if the box has been skewed - it will be larger.  Trying to work out that shape in Photoshop is far more complex problem.